# Reading large Excel files with c# and get the indexes

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, excel-interop, openxml-sdk

I tried to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel but it's too slow when it comes to reading large excel documents (it was taking over 5 minutes for me). I read that DocumentFormat.OpenXml is faster when it comes to reading large excel documents but in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-parse-and-read-a-large-spreadsheet) it doesn't appear that I can't store the columns and row indexes.

For now, I am also only interested in the first row to get the column headers and I will be reading the rest of the document after some logic. I haven't been able to find a way to read only a portion of the excel document. I want to do something similar to this:

```
        int r = 1;  //row index
        int c = 1;  //column index
        while (xlRange.Cells[r,c] != null && xlRange.Cells[r, c].Value2 != null)
        {
            TagListData.Add(new TagClass { IsTagSelected = false, TagName = xlRange[r, c].Value2.toString(), rIndex = r, cIndex = c });
            c += 3;
        }
```

Users will be picking excel documents through openFileDialog so there's no fixed number of rows of columns I can use. Is there a way I could make this work?

Thank you

Comment: Look into Accor.IO.ExcelReader, maybe that will help, but maybe not

Answer (score 1):

In OpenXML if a cell has no text it might or might not appear in the list of cells (depends on whether it ever had text or not). Therefore the `while (...Value2 != null)` type of approach isn't really a safe way to do things in OpenXML.

Here is a very simple approach to reading the first row (written using [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net) hence the `Main` and the `Dump`). Note the (simplified) use of the SharedStringTable to get the real text of the cell:

```
void Main()
{
    var fileName = @"c:\temp\openxml-read-row.xlsx";

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fs, false))
        {

            // Get the necessary bits of the doc
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = doc.WorkbookPart;
            SharedStringTablePart sstpart = workbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().First();
            SharedStringTable sst = sstpart.SharedStringTable;
            WorkbookStylesPart ssp = workbookPart.GetPartsOfType<WorkbookStylesPart>().First();
            Stylesheet ss = ssp.Stylesheet;

            // Get the first worksheet
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
            Worksheet sheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;

            var rows = sheet.Descendants<Row>();
            var row = rows.First();
            foreach (var cell in row.Descendants<Cell>())
            {
                var txt = GetCellText(cell, sst);
                // LINQPad specific method .Dump()
                $"{cell.CellReference} = {txt}".Dump();
            }
        }
    }   
}

// Very basic way to get the text of a cell
private string GetCellText(Cell cell, SharedStringTable sst)
{
    if (cell == null)
        return "";

    if ((cell.DataType != null) && (cell.DataType == CellValues.SharedString))
    {
        int ssid = int.Parse(cell.CellValue.Text);
        string str = sst.ChildElements[ssid].InnerText;
        return str;
    }
    else if (cell.CellValue != null)
    {
        return cell.CellValue.Text;
    }
    return "";
}
```

However... there's potentially a lot of work involved with OpenXML and you'd be well advised to try and use something like [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML) or [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) instead.

eg using ClosedXML

```
using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook(fileName))
{
    var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.First();
    var row = worksheet.Row(1);
    foreach (var cell in row.CellsUsed())
    {
        var txt = cell.Value.ToString();
        // LINQPad specific method .Dump()
        $"{cell.Address.ToString()} = {txt}".Dump();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't seem to be working for my excel file. It does seem to work for smaller excel documents (I tried this with a document with only one cell) but it appears to use too much memory for my larger excel file.

Comment: I found out that creating the instance of workbook is making my program slow. In my code I have: 
                string filename = openFileDialog.FileName;
                using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook(filename))
                {//everything here is commented out}
This alone is causing the error. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Seems that ClosedXML does (did?) have issues with large files. See here: https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues/86.  Seems there's a beta that may fix it.  Maybe you'll have to stick with the OpenXML approach and the file stream.  Or disable events as mentiond in the above issue: https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Turning-off-events.  Haven't had these issues myself so I don't have any insight I'm afraid.

Comment: I had to disable ContextSwitchDeadLock to the debugging menu. ClosedXML is working now but it still takes >8 minutes to read the file. I'm using ExcelDataReader now and it took 4-5 minutes to read the file but I'll try to look for a way to make it faster than that. Thank you though